# (Java) How do i make those loops generate a new string every time?

Tags: java, loops

Ok, so `hoehe` and `breite` are two ints that are grabbed from console input earlier. This works flawlessly. Now I want it to generate a random string with the lenght being the value of breite, print that out and then do that hoehe times. The only Characters the string can have are `/` and `\`. Right now it generates the string one time and then prints it out hoehe times.

```
int i = 0;
int y = 0;
double rand;
String output = "";
String case1 = "/";
String case2 = "\\";
while (y < hoehe) {
  while (i < breite) {
    rand = Math.random();
    if (rand < 0.5) {
      output += case1;
     }
    else {
        output += case2;
      }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(output);
    y++;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset `i`. Use for-loops instead:

```
double rand;
String output = "";
String case1 = "/";
String case2 = "\\";
for(int y = 0; y < hoehe; ++y) {
    for(int i = 0; i < breite; ++i) {
      rand = Math.random();
      if (rand < 0.5) {
        output += case1;
      }
      else {
        output += case2;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
  }
}
```

Comment: The entire `if-else` can be replaced to one line `output += Math.random() < 0.5 ? case1 : case2;`. Also, you might wanna change `++y` to `y++` and replace first three lines to `String output = "", case1 = "/", case2 = "\\";` to make it readable.

Comment: Thank you! after also adding output = ""; after printing out the string it works!

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Many people I know(and I personally) think that you shouldn't use commas for declaring multiple variables. It makes it less readable. It's a personal opinion tho. Since OP made a pretty basic mistake, I assume they are new to Programming. The replacement for the if-else you presented is often confusing for beginners. Also, I think `++y` is more efficient than `y++` because y++ stores the previous value to return it after being incremented, which requires an extra variable.

Comment: I find it more readable. Anyways, there is absolutely no performance gain when doing `++y` vs `y++` in Java. But let's just suppose there was a performance gain, then `output += case1` is ridiculous because you are concerned about performance increase of probably one cpu cycle per loop, you should demonstrate using a `StringBuilder` for performace in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
int y = 0;
double rand;
String output = "";
String case1 = "/";
String case2 = "\\";
  while (y < hoehe) {
    while (i < breite) {
      rand = Math.random();
      if (rand < 0.5) {
        output += case1;
      }
      else {
        output += case2;
      }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;  //////  add this
    System.out.println(output);
    y++;
  }
```